# Difference between functions.callUDF and functions.udf (error: data type mismatch)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm having some trouble creating a UDF from a lambda function that accepts a UserDefinedType.

If we use the (deprecated) `callUDF` function, everything works as expected:

```
// Works
featured.withColumn("parsed",
  functions.callUDF(myFunction, DoubleType, featured("elements")))

// Error
featured.withColumn("parsed",
  functions.udf(myFunction).apply((featured("elements"))))
```

The error thrown is:

"cannot resolve 'UDF(elements)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array type, however, 'elements' is of array type.;"

This looks like it might be bug in how functions.udf uses reflection to read the TypeTag of our UDT (called `determinedelemen` here). Thoughts about how to fix this? I'd rather not rely on a deprecated method.

EDIT: `featured` is a dataframe, assume it has a column called 'elements' in it of Seq[DeterminedElementUDT] type. myFunction has the following signature:

```
def myFunction: (Seq[DeterminedElement] => Double) = elements => {
    0.0 // actual calculation done here
}
```

Comment: could you post code (or signatures) of `myFunction` and `featured`?

Comment: done - the exact form of `featured` shouldn't matter (?) except that it is a DataFrame and it does have a column of type Seq[DeterminedElementUDT]

Comment: does this work?
    `val myUDF = udf(myFunction(_:Seq[DeterminedElement]))`
    `myUDF(featured("elements"))`

Comment: @DanieldePaula - sorry for the delayed reply: I get the same error with that (cannot resolve 'UDF(elements)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<determinedelemen> type, however, 'elements' is of array<determinedelemen> type.;)

code was:

    `val myUDF = functions.udf(myFunction(_: Seq[DeterminedElement]))
    featured.withColumn("myUDF_result", myUDF(featured("elements")))
      .select("myUDF_result", "elements")
      .show(10, truncate = false)`